# How do you refresh an advert served by Google Ad Manager after a javascript event (eg ajax postback) has occured on a webpage

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-ad-manager

I want to be able to re trigger the loading of an embedded admanager advert on the page after a user has clicked an ajax link on the page (effectively showing them a new page, so it's a genuine attempt to show another impression).

Preferably I want a solution that doesn't put adverts in an iFrame, uses jquery to perform the client side action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around a bit my advise is: Do not try to do this. It probably is a violation of google TOS.

I you still want to try it. Here a few links for a starter (but most still use `iframe` solutions as anything else most surely is against the TOS).

[AdSense and AJAX: Not a happy combination](http://nico.berlee.nl/adsense-and-ajax-not-a-happy-combination/)

[How to advertise on a pure AJAX application?](http://www.jguru.com/forums/view.jsp?EID=1305379)

[I can't use Google Ads in an AJAX panel](http://www.interaktonline.com/Support/Knowledgebase/Technote/Details/248/17/I+can't+use+Google+Ads+in+an+AJAX+panel.html)

[How to fetch new ads after an AJAX action (no page reload)](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Ad+Manager/thread?tid=6c5ddadca3930d28&hl=en)

https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/search.py?query=ajax